# Passing C function pointers between two python modules

Tags: python, c, function-pointers

I'm writing an application working with plugins. There are two types of plugins: `Engine` and `Model`. `Engine` objects have an `update()` method that call the `Model.velocity()` method.

For performance reasons these methods are *allowed* to be written in C. This means that sometimes they will be written in Python and sometimes written in C.

The problem is that this forces to do an expensive Python function call of `Model.velocity()` in `Engine.update()` (and also reacquiring the GIL). I thought about adding something like `Model.get_velocity_c_func()` to the API, that would allow `Model` implementations to return a pointer to the C version of their `velocity()` method if available, making possible for `Engine` to do a faster C function call.

What data type should I use to pass the function pointer ? And is this a good design at all, maybe there is an easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CObject (PyCOBject) data type exists for this purpose. It holds a void*, but you can store any data you wish. You do have to be careful not to pass the wrong CObject to the wrong functions, as some other library's CObjects will look just like your own.

If you want more type security, you could easily roll your own PyType for this; all it has to do, after all, is contain a pointer of the right type.

Comment: How can I pass this from my `Model` to the `Engine` ? all I have from the `Engine` point of view is a Python instance of the currently used `Model`, I don't know how to "call" the C code (which may not even exist) in the `Model` from the `Engine`.

Comment: I realize my comment does not make sense... I mean, how can I pass a PyCObject from C to Python ?

Comment: Never mind I understand now, I just do PyCObject_FromVoidPtr / PyCObject_AsVoidPtr on both sides, thanks :)